# Drools - fire only once when a condition in child List is met

Tags: drools

I would like the "then" clause to only execute one time, but it is executing for each child object in the list that matches.

If any item in the list meets the condition I want to break out and have only one execution of the then clause.

```
rule "Profile - Delinquent"  
    when  
        $c : CreditReportAll( $creditLiability : creditLiability )  
        $cs: CreditLiability( paymentPatternData.contains("X")) from $creditLiability  
    then  
        CreditUserSegment $cu = new CreditUserSegment();  
        $cu.setSegmentCode("delinquent");  
        $c.addUserSegmentToList($cu);  
    end
```

Comment: This is as simple as using the exists operator:

rule "Profile - Delinquent"  
    when  
        $c : CreditReportAll( $creditLiability : creditLiability )  
        exists ($cs: CreditLiability( paymentPatternData.contains("X")) from $creditLiability)  
    then  
        CreditUserSegment $cu = new CreditUserSegment();  
        $cu.setSegmentCode("delinquent");  
        $c.addUserSegmentToList($cu);  
end

Comment: Are you trying to answer your own question? I'm not sure how your comment relates to the question. If you're trying to answer, the box below the question  (heading "your answer") is where you should put your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to only fire the rule once when any item in the `$creditLiability` list meets the condition, you either need to write your rule such that it doesn't iterate across the list, or you need to update your rule so that once it does fire, it changes the facts in working memory to not allow it to fire again.

### No iteration

The easiest way to do this is to change your rule to not iterate across the list. To do this, we use the `exists` keyword like this:

```
rule "Profile - Delinquent"  
when
  $c : CreditReportAll( $creditLiability : creditLiability )
  exists( CreditLiability( paymentPatternData.contains("X")) from $creditLiability )
then  
  CreditUserSegment $cu = new CreditUserSegment();  
  $cu.setSegmentCode("delinquent");  
  $c.addUserSegmentToList($cu);  
end
```

The `exists` keyword will match when the there is at least one element present that matches the required condition. Note that we don't assign a variable to the result anymore, because it doesn't make any sense (eg. there's no assignment of `$cs` here; it would be ambiguous as to what it would even refer to.)

The downside to this approach is that if you update working memory in any other rule (eg by calling `insert`, `modify`, `update`, and so on), you may end up triggering this rule again because the conditions on the left hand side will still remain valid and matching. To alleviate this you may be able to leverage the [`no-loop` rule attribute](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#rules-attributes-ref_drl-rules) (depending on your setup). Otherwise you'll want to update your rule (or data in working memory) so that your rule is no longer valid.

### Invalidate the rule

The other way to only trigger the rule once is to make the rule no longer valid to fire after it fires once. A trivial way to do this (likely not best practice in this case) would be to insert a flag into working memory and check on its presence. In this case I will use a simple string "DELINQUENT" as the flag.

```
rule "Profile - Delinquent"  
when
  not(String(this == "DELINQUENT"))
  $c : CreditReportAll( $creditLiability : creditLiability )
  $cs: CreditLiability( paymentPatternData.contains("X")) from $creditLiability  
then  
  CreditUserSegment $cu = new CreditUserSegment();  
  $cu.setSegmentCode("delinquent");  
  $c.addUserSegmentToList($cu);
  insert("DELINQUENT");
end
```

When the rule fires, it inserts a string that says "DELINQUENT" into working memory. The rule conditions are such that the rule only fires if this string doesn't exist in working memory. Thus after the first execution, the rule will not execute again unless a rule retracts that string.

This solution increases the memory footprint of the rule execution because there is more information in working memory. However unlike the other solution (which is more elegant), this version will not re-fire if another rule retriggers execution (eg. via `update`.)